# Newtonsoft.Json System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I am getting the following exception and I am not sure how to resolve it. I do not want to set `AllowSynchronousIO = true`. MS has made the decision starting with 3.0 to no longer allow synchronous by default and for good reason. So how do I get around this issue?

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call ReadAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer(Span`1 userBuffer, Boolean& readToUserBuffer)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadSpan(Span`1 buffer)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadData(Boolean append, Int32 charsRequired)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasync?view=netcore-3.1 or wait till/if Json.Net support DeserializeAsync... (assuming you don't want to read stream yourself)

Comment: If the payloads are large enough that the JSON document can't be read in one go and you can't make them smaller, then I think your only real alternatives are to either set `AllowSynchronousIO` to `true` (possibly even just per-request where needed), or remove usage of Newtonsoft.Json and use System.Text.Json (or some other async-supporting serializer) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream` class as a wrapper around the stream solves the issue. This allows you to access a stream asynchronously and then expose the stream to a synchronous tool like Newtonsoft.Json without enabling SynchronousIO for the entire solution. MVC is getting around this error by using the FileBufferingReadStream class as well so it's well tested.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.filebufferingreadstream?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Github issue that talks about this particular change and why microsoft made the change. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7644